# How to find + convert on these .gif?

Tags: debian, find, conversion

I want `find` a list of .gif files, `convert` them all to series of `png` images with filename identifiers and loop those series in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373780/13173) LaTeX. 
I am thining here how to combine the `find` + `convert`.

1. I can list .gif file by :

   ```
   find -L *.gif -type f
   ```
2. I can convert .gif image to a series of png images BUT without own identifier

   ```
   # TODO take filename from find list and give to convert and to the resulted filename
   convert -coalesce giphy.gif out%05d.png
   ```

Pseudocode where `{}.png` tries to say that take the new filename from the list of filenames but I think it cannot work because the list contains also `.gif` extension so it should be removed :

```
find -L *.gif -type f -exec convert -coalesce {} {}.png +
```

OS: Debian 8.7

Comment: Is your question about using the basename of each file found as the basename of the corresponding converted output files? if so you should be able to do something like `find -L . -name '*.gif' -execdir sh -c 'for f; do convert -coalesce "$f" "${f%.gif}%05d.png"; done' sh {} +`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it seems to be correct. What is the role role of `-execdir` here? - - So you apply a sh loop on a gif image for each list image.  Yes, that seems to be correct. - - Do you have any proposal how to find the image series info now to LaTeX and loop it in the linked LaTeX code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steeldriver's great answer in comment

```
 find -L . -name '*.gif' -execdir sh -c 'for f; 
      do convert -coalesce "$f" "${f%.gif}%05d.png"; 
 done' sh {} +
```

Comment: I extended the LaTeX part integration here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374073/13173

Answer (score 2):

With zsh

```
autoload -U zmv # best in ~/.zshrc

splitgif() convert -coalesce "$@"
zmv -p splitgif './(***/)(*).gif(#q-.)' './${1//\%/%%}${2//\%/%%}%05d.png'
```

Note the need for `./` to avoid problems with files named `gif:whatever.gif` for instance and `${1//\%/%%}` to escape the `%` characters that may be found in the file paths.

- `***` is the same as `**` but follows symlinks when descending the directory tree like your `-L`
- `(#q...)` glob qualifier
- `-`: apply the following checks to the target of the symlink for symlinks (`stat()` instead `lstat()`) like with your `-L`.
- `.`: only regular files (equivalent of `-type f`)

Comment: This answer sounds even better than the first one. - - I am thinking if Zsh can be integrated with LaTeX. It would mean to call Zsh from `bashful` package in LaTEX but no experience. My goal https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/374073/13173 but not sure if one step possible or 2 step approach better. What do you think?

Comment: @Léo, in your `bash` code, you should be able to do `zsh << 'EOZ'` with the zsh code below (terminated by a line with `EOZ`). Or `zsh /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOZ'` if the zsh code needs to do something with stdin.